# Visualforce Syntax Error for IF statement inside a Apex Repeat

Tags: visualforce

I am receiving a syntax error and having a hard time identifying where I am going wrong.

I have researched several different alternatives such as wrapping `<apex outputText>` as well as using multiple version of `{!` leading into my variable calls.  Unfortunately, I'm just having a hard time grasping which series of errors I am making to cause this syntax error.

The Crux of the code is:

```
<td>
{! IF(isTenant, ${woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate_Retail__c}, ${woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate__c})}
</td>
```

For variable References.  This is located in a  where woli is defined as:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!woliList}" var="woli">
```

and isTenant is simply hardcoded in my controller to be false for testing purposes:

```
public Boolean isTenant = False;
```

I expected my Apex Repeat command to populate different bill rates depending on the value of isTenant, but of course with the Syntax error I cannot tell if I am on the right track.  Helpful tips on when multiple {!} are or are not required in Visual Force references would be helpful.  I am also curious when, if ever, I should be using single or double quotation marks to define the output of the if condition.

UPDATE:

I thought perhaps I it was as simple as me not binding the condition statement to a variable in the controller class so I modified to this:

```
  <td>
    {! IF({!isTenant}, ${woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate_Retail__c}, ${woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate__c})}
    </td>
```

Adding appropriate get/set in the controller.  But alas this was not the problem the developer console still gives a mystery Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$` signs. Dollar is used for special fields that "depends who's looking" and other stuff not really related to data in database. You can have `$CurrentPage`, `$User.Name`, `$Profile.Name`, `$Label.someText` (that one counts as "depends who's looking" because if your preferred language is French it can display translated version.

And second thing - if you're already inside the `{! some merge field syntax }` you don't need more curly braces.

Try

```
{! IF(!isTenant,
    woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate_Retail__c,
    woli.Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate__c
)}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  For reference the $ was because the currency field doesn't display the dollar sign.  So I was adding that as a raw character in front of the calls.  Of course I moved that to in front of the {! because it was silly I was including it twice inside the braces.  Thanks again sir!

Comment: if it's currency field you could try apex:outputField or apex:outputText with that magic "¤" symbol in the formatter. Glad I helped :) Sometimes you waste so much time on simple things